# PresentViewController found nil value on instantiateViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, presentviewcontroller

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView.tag == 2{

            switch indexPath.item {
            case 0:
               if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "offersScreen") as? OffersVC {
                vc.cityID = self.cityID!
                vc.categoryID = indexPath.item + 1
                vc.headingLBL.text =  self.names[indexPath.item]
                vc.cityLBL.text = self.selectCity.text!
                    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }   
            case 1:
                print("You're heading VC 1!")
            case 2:
                print("You're heading VC 2!")
            case 3:
                print("You're heading VC 3!")
            default:
                print("Something went wrong")
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vXAJ.png)

I wrote everything perfect idk what I made mistake. It found nil value on on present. I present viewcontroller from tabbar viewController with 4 values
Please help or guide.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is all outlets are nil until the vc loads

**options #1**

```
 vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
 vc.headingLBL.text =  self.names[indexPath.item]
```

**options #2**

make vars of what you need to send

```
class OffersVC:UIViewController {
   var sendedStr = ""
```

then inside `viewDidLoad`

```
self.headingLBL = sendedStr
```

Comment: Yes, You are right option #2 is correct.
I found it before reading your answer. But Thanks you so much,

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your image description, I think the problem is that you are trying to unwrap 'headingLBL' without first initialising it.

See [Swift Xcode "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553295/swift-xcode-exc-bad-instruction)